# OSMnx Visualize the graph of edge centrality on Folium

Tags: python, matplotlib, openstreetmap, networkx, osmnx

I'm trying to plot the graph of edge centrality on the folium using the following code

[image]

```py
graph_map = ox.plot_graph_folium(G,
                                 popup_attribute='name',
                                 tiles='stamenterrain',
                                 edge_color=ec,
                                 edge_width=2)
```

where `ec` is list of edge colors but it is not showing up. Does `edge_color` accept a list of colors ? Any ideas?

I really appreciate if you can help me.

https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/08-example-line-graph.ipynb

Comment: Can you provide a fuller example (see [mcve]).  What is the module `ox`?

Comment: I try the example from this notebook https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/08-example-line-graph.ipynb @Joel

Comment: It appears to me that `plot_graph_folium` may not allow a list of colors, but rather only a single color string (I haven't found anything definitive, but it looks that way).  Is it feasible to do a separate plotting command for each color?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with OSMnx. See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67115678/7321942

Comment: Your links are now dead so I can't follow any of this Q&A. Please make your question self-contained

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding a new column of edge color to gdf of the graph edges

```py
gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G,
                             nodes=False,
                             fill_edge_geometry=True)
gdf_edges['edge_color'] = ec
```

Then modify two function

```
make_folium_polyline(edge, edge_width, edge_opacity, popup_attribute=None)
```

and

```
plot_graph_folium(gdf_edges, graph_map=None, popup_attribute=None, 
                      tiles='cartodbpositron', zoom=1, fit_bounds=True, 
                      edge_width=5, edge_opacity=1)
```

The final result is achieved:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand the modification. Could you please elaborate?