# OSMnx: plot a network on an interactive web map with different colours per infrastructure

Tags: python, networkx, openstreetmap, folium, osmnx

I'm trying to plot a network where edges have different colors according to their Opens street map attribute ('highway').  It works if I use `ox.graph`, however, this generates a static map. If I use `ox.plot.plot_graph_folium()` I only get an interactive map if I set all edges to have the same color. If I assign to edge_color a list of colors it doesn't work.

```
    import osmnx as ox
    address_name='19, Molstraat, Van Leeuwenhoekkwartier, Delft, South      Holland, Netherlands, 2611EM, Netherlands'

    graph=ox.graph_from_address(address_name, distance=300)

    ec = ['skyblue' if data['highway']=='footway' 
      else 'paleturquoise' if data['highway']=='residential' 
      else 'orange' if data['highway']=='cycleway' 
      else 'sienna' if data['highway']=='service' 
      else 'lightgreen' if data['highway']=='living street' 
      else 'grey' if data['highway']=='secondary'
      else 'lightskyblue' if data['highway']=='pedestrian'
      else 'black' for u, v, key, data in graph.edges(keys=True, data=True)]

    #this works, but is static
    ox.plot_graph(graph,fig_height=8,fig_width=8,node_size=0, edge_color=ec)

    #this does not work 
    import folium 
    ox.plot.plot_graph_folium(graph, popup_attribute='highway',edge_color=ec)

    #this works, but is one color only 
    import folium 
         ox.plot.plot_graph_folium(graph,popup_attribute='highway',edge_color='blue')
```

This similar question ([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49546015/osmnx-visualize-the-graph-of-edge-centrality-on-folium)) suggests adding a new column to each edge and then modify the `plot_graph_folium` function. Also, this modification is not working. Could someone provide me with an example of how to make an interactive map with edges of different colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use OSMnx to create an interactive Leaflet web map with edges colored by type.

The OSMnx `plot_graph_folium` function can accept an edge `color` argument as a keyword argument (see [the docs](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.folium)) that it just passes along to `folium.PolyLine` (see [here](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/d05793421df8da4d937d566ebeae4550f9f1dbc6/osmnx/folium.py#L228)). According to the folium [docs](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.vector_layers.PolyLine), folium in turn just passes the keyword argument along to Leaflet. See the Leaflet docs [here](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#polyline). Thus, there is no *built-in* way for OSMnx (as of the current release, v1.0.1) to create a Leaftlet web map with each edge given its own color. However, you *can* create an interactive Leaflet web map with edges colored by type (i.e., their `highway` value) with OSMnx, using a bit of code like this:

```py
import osmnx as ox
address = '19, Molstraat, Van Leeuwenhoekkwartier, Delft'
G = ox.graph_from_address(address, dist=300)

# define the colors to use for different edge types
hwy_colors = {'footway': 'skyblue',
              'residential': 'paleturquoise',
              'cycleway': 'orange',
              'service': 'sienna',
              'living street': 'lightgreen',
              'secondary': 'grey',
              'pedestrian': 'lightskyblue'}

# return edge IDs that do not match passed list of hwys
def find_edges(G, hwys):
    edges = []
    for u, v, k, data in G.edges(keys=True, data='highway'):
        check1 = isinstance(data, str) and data not in hwys
        check2 = isinstance(data, list) and all([d not in hwys for d in data])
        if check1 or check2:
            edges.append((u, v, k))
    return set(edges)

# first plot all edges that do not appear in hwy_colors's types
G_tmp = G.copy()
G_tmp.remove_edges_from(G.edges - find_edges(G, hwy_colors.keys()))
m = ox.plot_graph_folium(G_tmp, popup_attribute='highway', weight=5, color='black')

# then plot each edge type in hwy_colors one at a time
for hwy, color in hwy_colors.items():
    G_tmp = G.copy()
    G_tmp.remove_edges_from(find_edges(G_tmp, [hwy]))
    if G_tmp.edges:
        m = ox.plot_graph_folium(G_tmp,
                                 graph_map=m,
                                 popup_attribute='highway',
                                 weight=5,
                                 color=color)
m
```

[image: OSMnx folium leaflet interactive web map with street network edges colored by highway type]

Note that this solution can handle both simplified and unsimplified OSMnx edges (simplified edges can have multiple `highway` values). It will draw the edge each time it finds one of its edge types in the dictionary of types:colors. You can make this more precise by using an unsimplified graph (see OSMnx docs for details).