# Is it possible to draw paths in Folium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, maps, data-science, folium

I read many documentations related to this, but can't find something what I am looking for.

I want to plot walking paths between two points. Is it possible? if not, is there any other library in python for this purpose ?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56234047/7321942

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Of course, you can. Use [`PolyLine`](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.vector_layers.PolyLine):

```py
import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[40.720, -73.993],
              zoom_start=15)

loc = [(40.720, -73.993),
       (40.721, -73.996)]

folium.PolyLine(loc,
                color='red',
                weight=15,
                opacity=0.8).add_to(m)
m
```

and you get:

[image]

---

**EDIT 1**

In order to draw a **walking path** between two points, you can use a combination of [`OSMnx`](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx) and [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/):

```py
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx

ox.config(log_console=True,
          use_cache=True)

G_walk = ox.graph_from_place('Manhattan Island, New York City, New York, USA',
                             network_type='walk')

orig_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G_walk,
                                (40.748441, -73.985664))

dest_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G_walk,
                                (40.748441, -73.4))

route = nx.shortest_path(G_walk, orig_node, dest_node, weight='length')

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph_route(G_walk,
                              route,
                              node_size=0,
                              save=True,
                              file_format='svg',
                              filename='test')
```

and you get:

[image]

---

**EDIT 2**

For a folium-type map you can use [`plot_route_folium`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.plot.plot_route_folium):

```py
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx

ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)

G_walk = ox.graph_from_place('Manhattan Island, New York City, New York, USA',
                             network_type='walk')

orig_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G_walk,
                                (40.748441, -73.985664))

dest_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G_walk,
                                (40.748441, -73.4))

route = nx.shortest_path(G_walk,
                         orig_node,
                         dest_node,
                         weight='length')

route_map = ox.plot_route_folium(G_walk, route)

route_map.save('route.html')
```

and you get a useful html file:

[image]

Comment: is it drawing a walking path or is it just sketching a line?

Comment: It is a path, as you asked in your title *Is it possible to draw paths in Folium?* Are you looking for explicit walking paths?

Comment: Is it possible to plot routes without using the get_nearest_node function? i.e. if I have two precise house addresses, for example.

Comment: @sentenceis there a way to make those points a variable on the map that can be updated?