# Networkx OSMNX and Folium plotting different coloured edges

Tags: networkx, folium, osmnx

I have been trying to overlay different osmnx plots onto folium but I have been unable to. I want to achieve the same thing as shown in the image below with a simple osmnx plot but instead on folium with the red edges being red and the other edges being a different colour.

```
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph_routes(G,max_response_edges, bgcolor='k', node_size=30, node_color='#999999', node_edgecolor='none', node_zorder=2,
                        edge_color='#555555', edge_linewidth=1.5, edge_alpha=1,figsize = (20,20))
```

[image]

I have tried to use the following code:

```
H = G.copy()
H1 = G.copy()
H.remove_edges_from(G.edges - set(map(lambda x: tuple(x)+(0,),max_response_edges)))
m = ox.folium.plot_graph_folium(H,tiles='openstreetmap',popup_attribute='name',opacity = 1,color = 'red',weight= 10)
H1.remove_edges_from(set(map(lambda x: tuple(x)+(0,),max_response_edges)))
n = ox.folium.plot_graph_folium(H1,tiles='openstreetmap',popup_attribute='name',opacity = 1,color = 'blue',weight= 10)
n.add_to(m)
m
```

[image]

I tried making use of `m.add_child()` or `m.add_to()` but none have proved useful. A similar stack overflow question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56234047/osmnx-plot-a-network-on-an-interactive-web-map-with-different-colours-per-infra/67115678#67115678) however this did not work. Can folium overlays be done?

Comment: "however this did not work" -- it would help if you could unpack this aspect in detail, as that prior answer was the one that I would give.

Comment: hello @gboeing. I only get the image shown above with red edges only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working through the following code

```
H = G.copy()
H1 = G.copy()
H.remove_edges_from(G.edges - set(map(lambda x: tuple(x)+(0,),max_response_edges)))
m = ox.folium.plot_graph_folium(H,tiles='openstreetmap',popup_attribute='name',opacity = 1,color = 'red',weight= 10)
H1.remove_edges_from(set(map(lambda x: tuple(x)+(0,),max_response_edges)))
m = ox.folium.plot_graph_folium(H1, graph_map = m,tiles='openstreetmap',popup_attribute='name',opacity = 1,color = 'blue',weight= 10)
m
```

turns out I was missing the `graph_map=m` parameter